# Should I ask personal coaching questions? How?

Tags: discussion

Suppose I want to learn technique X. "How to learn X?" would be a good question here, but I already know from elsewhere that I should do A, B and C, while paying attention to D, E and F. I started doing all that, but I am stuck with no progress.

**Why no progress? How to achieve it anyway?** — this is my question, and I wonder how I can make it answerable, and whether it's a good fit for this site at all.

The answer may be personal — something that would only help me and no one else (but maybe other people in the world have a similar problem). Also, it's probably impossible to answer without showing what I did (videos). From what I see in this site, such questions are not welcome.

Should I ask such questions? If yes, how?

Comment: For clarity, what exactly is your situation?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see anything wrong with asking a personalized question. In fact, adding those personal details often leads to important situation-specific nuances being addressed in the answers. We aren't trying to build up a general cycling encyclopedia (haha) here. As you said, people may have similar problems and the information presented is likely to be useful still.

Also, there's no harm in asking the question anyways and letting the upvote/downvote and close votes system work its magic. If you get overwhelmingly negative feedback, perhaps the question needs to be rephrased or deleted.

In terms of asking the question itself, I would suggest including your current understanding of the situation, what you've already tried, what you're stuck on, what resources you have/don't have, and some photos/videos of the situation. There's no hard and fast rules though. Make the question yours!

Comment: I would agree, a question that seems unique to just one person is usually applicable to others as well. There are plenty of examples of this on BE.